# How to grant access to audio files without downloading

Tags: javascript, php, audio, ionic2, streaming

I want to grant access to audio files for some group of people - now in the browser but in future in Ionic / Cordova app as well. But Access to them will be after authentication and I want to protect against downloading them.

What will be the best way to do it?

- put files to some service for audio files - similar to youtube?
- streaming from server - I use PHP?
- use flash app?

Thanks for any solutions,

Comment: Forget about flash, its dead. YouTube would be one of the best choices out there. Or maybe soundcloud.

Comment: Both Soundcloud and Youtube can be accessed without authentication though @jrSakizci

Comment: @Luca - I am sorry but i dont think there are services for this. You probably should find & write your own service for this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would suggest too

Comment: While you can disable the ability to explicitly "Save as..." you can't "prevent downloading." Playing the file inherently downloads it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think SoundClound will be the best option at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, to video files you can't prevent someone form downloading a file if you want to stream it to their device.

Ultimately, the file has to get to the device and there are many ways to store it even if you try to make it hard.

The usual approach to take is to DRM protect the files - this is commonly used by the paid music services.

Audio DRM is a little different from video, because most devices do not have a secure media pipeline for audio, which means it is a little less secure.

Ultimately, all these measures are hurdles and detergents - it generally ends up being as much a business solution as anything. If the user perceives that the cost is not too high for the service, or is low enough not to bother circumventing, then they are more likely to use it legitimately.